# Do the higher level SSE flags imply the lower ones in GCC / clang?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, sse

For example, if you use -msse4, does this imply that it will also use -mssse3, -msse3, -msse2 and so on or do you have to explicitly add those flags as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need the highest level switch, e.g. `-mssse3` implies `-msse3`, `-msse2` etc. It doesn't cause any problems if you add the lower level switches, but they are redundant.

Comment: @bleater: this is just based on empirical evidence - it's easy to check though using `gcc -dM -E - <other flags> < /dev/null`.